# PostgreSQL inverse query with JOINS

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

With the below schema, I am trying to get all employees in department 1 and also have their excuse for being absent (if any) for a particular date as below.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
id     | department |      full_name    |  excuse      | date
-------+------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------
    10 |      Sales | John Doe          | NULL         | 2019-01-20
    20 |      Sales | James Brown       | NULL         | 2019-01-20
    30 |      Sales | Adam Sanders      | Fatigued     | 2019-01-20
    70 |      Sales | Amber Philips     | NULL         | 2019-01-20
```

I have tried the below query but I haven't been able to get it right.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(emp.id) as employee_id, 
emp.full_name, ab.excuse
dept.name AS department 
FROM employees emp
INNER JOIN departmens dept ON emp.department_id = dept.id
LEFT JOIN absence ab ON ab.employee_id = emp.id
WHERE emp.department_id IN (1)  
AND emp.id NOT IN (
    SELECT att.employee_id FROM attendance att 
    INNER JOIN employees emp ON att.employee_id = emp.id
    WHERE emp.department_id IN (1)
    AND att.date BETWEEN SYMMETRIC '2019-01-20' AND '2019-01-20'
)
```

**EMPLOYEES**

```
-----------------------------------------
id     | department |      full_name  
-------+------------+--------------------
    10 |          1 | John Doe           
    20 |          1 | James Brown        
    30 |          1 | Adam Sanders   
    40 |          3 | Craig Wallace
    50 |          3 | Lina Goode
    60 |          6 | Jenny Rosewood 
    70 |          1 | Amber Philips
```

**ATTENDANCE**

```
----------------------------------------
id     | employee_id |  attendance_date
-------+-------------+------------------
     1 |          10 | 2019-01-20
     2 |          20 | 2019-01-20
```

**ABSENCE**

```
-------------------------------------------------------
id     | employee_id |       excuse       | date
-------+-------------+--------------------+------------
     1 |          30 | Fatigued           | 2019-01-20
     2 |          20 | Feeling Sick       | 2019-01-18
     3 |          10 | Out Of town        | 2019-01-15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your desired `result`, you don't need a `subquery`. Your `left join` is enough.

```
select distinct(emp.id) as employee_id
    , dept.name
    , emp.full_name
    , ab.excuse
    , ab.date
from employees emp
inner join departmens dept on emp.department_id = dept.id
left join absence ab on ab.employee_id = emp.id and ab.date =  '2019-01-20' 
where emp.department_id in (1)
```